# Is there an attribute that I can use with ASP.NET MVC 3 to prevent model fields from being automatically included in my views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, razor

Is there an attribute that I can use with ASP.NET MVC 3 to prevent model fields from automatically showing up in my view?  What I mean by this is that I have classes like the following:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //more fields...
}

public class TestEntity : EntityBase
{
    public string TestEntityName { get; set; }
    //more fields...
}
```

I know about all of the attributes in `System.ComponentModel` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` to enforce validation - `Required`, `StringLength`, etc. - but is there one I can use that will prevent certain fields from showing up in the view when I create it from Visual Studio?  All of my project's model classes inherit from `EntityBase`, but I don't want any of `EntityBase`'s fields to be visible on the view.  I'm using Razor as my ViewEngine, in case it matters.

TIA,

Benjy

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want them included?  If they're truly attributes of the model, aren't they necessary in order to properly describe a particular object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ScaffoldColumn:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

Comment: Also, for anybody who's interested in poking around on the template files (T4) used to generate these, go to *Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates* (substituting appropriate values for your machine) - if you do, you'll notice that the Scaffold property is one test used to determine whether a field appears on the generated forms.